# How Do I Deploy A Constantly-Running Application To Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I want to create a program that runs constantly and checks a status every minute or so, then calls a separate service if a condition is met.

Could this work in Azure Service Fabric?

I started looking into how to try to do it as a "Guest Executable" but I'm not sure I'm headed in the right direction.

I'm trying to keep things PaaS, not full-blown IaaS via VM with a Windows Service or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services in Service Fabric are always running. So, you can simply use the method `RunAsync` inside a Service, to run a loop.

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      while (true)
      {                
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            DoStuff();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),cancellationToken);
      }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I'll check into this. Another newb question: will this work as a simple "Stateless Service"? I'm still figuring out all the different service types.

Comment: Sure, the RunAsync is available in both models. The choice only depends on whether you need to keep state inside the service.